# Image display in ASP

Tags: html, image, vbscript, asp-classic

How can i display an image with a direct link (such as "http://www.utexas.edu/courses/mis325/hw/hw11a.gif") when coding with asp/vb?

Comment: Please pay more attention to your tag choices, specifically the big "DO NOT USE" message on the pop up help text for the `asp` tag. Choose either `asp.net` or `asp-classic` instead. The `vb` tag is similar.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the question. Like this?...

`<a href="http://www.utexas.edu/courses/mis325/hw/hw11a.gif"><img src="http://www.utexas.edu/courses/mis325/hw/hw11a.gif" alt="" border="0"></a>`

You didn't say where it should link to, so I assumed to the same image?
Also, this is a plain HTML link, not sure what you mean by how to do it in ASP/VB

Comment: @Konrad: It this answers your question you should mark it as such.